# How can i split date-time column "2019-05-01T08:00:00+00:00" into two date and time columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have tried to split date-time column of this format `2019-05-01T08:00:00+00:00` into two columns 'Date' and 'Time' to no avail. Column name is `YearTime` and I have coded it as follows:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(sf$YearTime)
df$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(df$YearTime), format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Below is what I get:

```
YearTime                       Date          Time      
2019-05-01T08:00:00+00:00      2019-05-01    00:00:00
2019-05-01T08:15:00+00:00      2019-05-01    00:00:00
```

I don't need `00:00:00` under the 'Time' column, instead i need the following format:

```
    YearTime                       Date          Time      
    2019-05-01T08:00:00+00:00      2019-05-01    08:00:00
    2019-05-01T08:15:00+00:00      2019-05-01    08:15:00
```

FYI, the 'Time' column has 15-minute interval. Any idea of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Specify the format explicitly in `as.POSIXct`.

```
df$YearTime <- as.POSIXct(df$YearTime, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', tz = 'UTC')
df$Date <- as.Date(df$YearTime)
df$Time <- format(df$YearTime, format = "%H:%M:%S") 
df

#             YearTime       Date     Time
#1 2019-05-01 08:00:00 2019-05-01 08:00:00
#2 2019-05-01 08:15:00 2019-05-01 08:15:00
```

Using `lubridate` you can use `ymd_hms` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(YearTime = ymd_hms(YearTime), 
         Date = as.Date(YearTime), 
         Time = format(YearTime, format = "%H:%M:%S"))
```

**data**

It is easier to help if your provide data in a reproducible format.

```
df <- structure(list(YearTime = c("2019-05-01T08:00:00+00:00", 
"2019-05-01T08:15:00+00:00")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

We could also use `tidyr::separate` and set `sep` argument to `"T"`  character between your `Date` and `Time` values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(YearTime, c("Date", "Time"), "T") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), 
         Time = format(as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%H:%M:%S"), format = "%H:%M:%S"))

        Date     Time
1 2019-05-01 08:00:00
2 2019-05-01 08:15:00
```

If you want to keep your original `YearTime` value, set `remove = FALSE` in `separate`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way: Using `str_extract`, `regex`, and `lubridate` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%  
    mutate(Date = ymd(str_extract(YearTime, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")),
           Time = hms(str_extract_all(YearTime, "(?<=T).+(?=\\+)")))
```

Output:

```
  YearTime                  Date       Time     
  <chr>                     <date>     <Period> 
1 2019-05-01T08:00:00+00:00 2019-05-01 8H 0M 0S 
2 2019-05-01T08:15:00+00:00 2019-05-01 8H 15M 0S
```

Comment: Those regex(s) are awesome brother!

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
 df %>% 
    mutate(YearTime = ymd_hms(YearTime), Date = as.Date(YearTime),
     Time = as.ITime(YearTime))
             YearTime       Date     Time
1 2019-05-01 08:00:00 2019-05-01 08:00:00
2 2019-05-01 08:15:00 2019-05-01 08:15:00
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
transform(df, Date = trimws(YearTime, whitespace = "T.*"), 
      Time = trimws(YearTime, whitespace = ".*T|\\+.*"))
                   YearTime       Date     Time
1 2019-05-01T08:00:00+00:00 2019-05-01 08:00:00
2 2019-05-01T08:15:00+00:00 2019-05-01 08:15:00
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(YearTime = c("2019-05-01T08:00:00+00:00", 
"2019-05-01T08:15:00+00:00")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```